# Blazor: Input binding not triggering method on parent component

Tags: blazor-server-side

blazor8 server side components
Explanation:
I'm working on a Blazor application where I have a parent component (UserManagement.razor) and a child component (UserFilter.razor). The child component is responsible for filtering a list of users displayed in the parent component. The issue I'm facing is that when I change the filter term in the child component, the method in the parent component (HandleFilter) is not being triggered.
I have tried various approaches, including using @bind, @oninput, and EventCallback, but the method in the parent component is still not being called. I've included the relevant code snippets below for reference.
UserFilter.razor:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Filter..." @bind="Value" @oninput="HandleInput" />
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    private async Task HandleInput(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Value = e.Value?.ToString();
        await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
    }
}
<!-- UserManagement.razor -->
<h3>User Management</h3>
<UserFilter Value="@filterTerm" ValueChanged="HandleFilter" />
<table>
    <!-- Rest of your code remains the same -->
</table>
@code {
    private string filterTerm;

    private async Task HandleFilter(string value)
    {
        filterTerm = value;
        // Call your filtering logic or any other necessary action
        FilterUsers();
    }
}
```